# Using Javascript to convert radians to degrees with positive and negative values

Tags: javascript, html, rotation, sprite

I am writing a game in HTML5 and having problems with a piece of Javascript to do with the conversion of radians to degrees.

Currently my sprite is turned when the left and right keys on the keyboard are pressed/held down. The framework I am using outputs the rotation value in radians however the number can go above/below 1 and -1. Each time the right key applies a +0.05 to the rotation value and -0.05 from the left key.

Everything works fine when I constantly rotate clockwise (right key) using the following code:

```js
game.player.rotationdeg = (ship.rotation * (180/Math.PI)) % 360;
```

Even if I go through a full rotation over 360 degrees the resulting degrees start back at 0 and continues to provide the correct angle.

When I go counter clockwise and the rotation value goes below 0 then things go out of whack. Instead of 270 degrees I get -90. This is causing me a lot of time and stress and I would appreciate any assistance.

I believe I might be able to check if the result is a negative and then just minus it from 360 but I am unsure of where to put that in the code I have or if it needs a separate function to work it out. I believe it might just be a problem with how I am approaching the situation.

Comment: Additional info: the radian value can go up to high numbers say 20 for example, it will return the correct degrees ignoring how many full rotations there are in radians with the code I have posted.

Comment: I have tested this and it doesn't seem to behave the same way in the potential duplicate. It gives me the correct reading in terms of providing the modulo functionality - the result from going counter clockwise goes up to -360 and then still restarts at 0 like it should. The problem is the degrees it is outputting is not an absolute degree as much as an inverse degree. I would like an output of only 0 to 360. For example, I am currently getting 15 degrees if I go slighting clockwise but -15 if I go slightly counter clockwise. I would like to get 345 degrees instead of -15 degrees.

Comment: From what I understand, that's the issue the question is describing (that the result from JavaScript is negative), The answers provide the correct behaviour as far as I'm aware.

Comment: With my current code -2000 % 360 returns -160 which is correct as it is considering that the number is negative and works well in my situation. However the answer I am trying to get is 200 in this situation. I have posted a potential answer but am unsure if that will work 100% of the time.

Comment: The code you have posted there does work. It might just be my limited knowledge in the understanding of the modulo bug. I appreciate your help.

Comment: game.player.rotationdeg = (((ship.rotation * (180/Math.PI)) % 360) + 360) % 360;

Comment: Is that what you posted essentially? Should that work?

Comment: Yes, that will work. If you'd like you could put it into a separate function, but that's not necessary. Try that where `ship.rotation === -0.5 * pi`

Comment: Thank you friend. If you post this as an answer I would like to show my appreciation but if you feel it is a true duplicate I will delete my original post.

Comment: To be honest this feels a bit too much of a duplicate to answer for me, but take an upvote.